# как удалить origin git?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-branch

Не смог разобраться с гитхабом. По своей глупости несколько раз удалял репозиторий и создавал новый. В итоге проект пушиться не хотел (так и не разобрался) по этому пришлось менять origin master на origin11 master   origin1111 master  ну и так далее. Теперь такой вопрос. Как удалить все эти origin11 master ?  И как пушить просто изменения ? в visual studio code после каждого изменения делаю коммит (с этим вроде разобрался) , а дальше не понимаю

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git remote remove <name>` — удаление

`git remote rename <old> <new>` — переименование

Все подробности есть в справке https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote